# Execute Query after value from Multiselect in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-8

Hi I am working in Laravel.

I need to select all rows from databse with selected company_id. In form company_id is multi select

This is what I have done

```
$data = $request->All();
$notifyTo = $data['notify_to']; /**value from multiselect which is an array**/
foreach($notifyTo as $noTo => $value){
$user = User::all()->where('company_id', "=", $value)->where('status', "=", 1); 
            }
            print_r($user); exit;
```

here $data['notify_to'] is the value from multiselct , which is an array of `company_id` `Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 22 [2] => 33 )`

Table Structure

```
| id | name | company_id | status |
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Don't start your query with `::all()`; that loads _every record into memory_, then filters them via `Collection` methods, and you're doing that inside a `foreach()`... That's insane. I _think_ `User::whereIn('company_id', $data['notify_to'])->where('status', 1)->get()` should do what you want, but you should clarify what `$data['notify_to']` contains.

Comment: @TimLewis here $data['notify_to'] is the value from multiselct , which is an array of company_id **Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 22 [2] => 33 )**

Comment: Then yes, `$users = User::whereIn('company_id', $data['notify_to'])->where('status', 1)->get();` will return a `Collection` of all `users` records that have a `company_id` value of `11, 22, 33`, etc., and `status` of `1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
User::whereIn('company_id', $data['notify_to'])->where('status', 1)->get();
```

It will solve your issue.

If you have multiple filters and you want to add multiple "if conditions" if filters are set properly then use the following code structure.

```
$query = User::where('status', 1);

if (isset(filters['filtername']) {
  $query->where(filters['filtername']);
}

multiple filter conditions.
...
... 

$userObject = $query->get;
```

It will give you a collection of users based on applied filters.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`whereIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) clause

```
$data = $request->All();
$notifyTo = $data['notify_to'];
$user =  User::whereIn('company_id', $notifyTo)->whereStatus(1)->get();
print_r($user);
```

> Make sure `$notifyTo` is an index array. If not use [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)